# How can I combine bins along xaxis in a barchart using plotly and python?

Tags: python, plotly

How can I combine bins along xaxis in a barchart using plotly and python?

Here is what I tried:

```
data3 = Data([
    Bar(
        x=[x[0] for x in lv_list],
        y=[(y[1]/lc_dict[y[0]]) for y in lv_list]
    )
])
layout3 = dict(
   title='Public Highlight Analysis',
   yaxis=YAxis(
       title = 'Average Number of Views'),
   xaxis1=XAxis(
       title = "Duration of Highlight in Seconds",
        autotick=False,
        dtick=50, range = [0,10000])
   )
fig3 = Figure(data=data3, layout=layout3)
py.iplot(fig3)
```

[image]

What I want to do:

I want the graph to combine the numbers between 1-1000, 1001-2000, 2001-3000, etc so that there are 6 bins along the axis.

Comment: and by "combine" you mean sum?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean by "combine", but here are a couple of possible solutions.

Sample data:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
y = [2, 1, 6, 3, 7, 9, 2, 12,5, 3]
s = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
```

1 - If you just want to display fewer ticks, use `dtick` inside `xaxis` (https://plot.ly/python/reference/#XAxis)

Here is the default view:

```
>> py.iplot([Bar(x=x, y=y)])
```

[image: Default bar chart]

Here, with custom `dtick`:

```
iplot({
    'data': [
        Bar(x=x, y=y)
    ], 
    'layout': {
        'xaxis': {
            'dtick': 3
        }
    }
})
```

[image: Display a tick every 3 items with <code>dtick</code>]

2 - If you want your items binned by frequency, use a histogram ([more histogram examples](https://plot.ly/python/histograms))

```
py.iplot([Histogram(y=y)])
```

[image: Simple histogram]

3 - If you want your items binned and summed, consider using Pandas:

```
>> import pandas as pd
>> df = pd.DataFrame({'x': x, 'y': y, 's': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']})
>> df

   s   x   y
0  A   1   2
1  B   2   1
2  C   3   6
3  D   4   3
4  A   5   7
5  B   6   9
6  C   7   2
7  D   8  12
8  E   9   5
9  F  10   3
```

use `groupby` and `sum` to bin and sum all of your items that belong to the same category

```
>> s = df.groupby('s').sum()
>> s
    x   y
s        
A   6   9
B   8  10
C  10   8
D  12  15
E   9   5
F  10   3
>> py.iplot([Bar(x=s.index, y=s.y)])
```

[image: binned bar chart example]

If your data is numerical, and you want to bin and sum the values, then create the numerical bins yourself and plot the result:

```
>> import numpy as np
>> bins = np.linspace(df.x.min(), df.x.max(), 5)
>> print bins
[  1.     3.25   5.5    7.75  10.  ]
>> df['groups'] = np.digitize(df.x, bins)
>> print df

   s   x   y  groups
0  A   1   2       1
1  B   2   1       1
2  C   3   6       1
3  D   4   3       2
4  A   5   7       2
5  B   6   9       3
6  C   7   2       3
7  D   8  12       4
8  E   9   5       4
9  F  10   3       5

>> grouped = df.groupby('groups').sum()
>> print grouped
         x   y
groups        
1        6   9
2        9  10
3       13  11
4       17  17
5       10   3

>> bin_boundaries = [_ - 0.5 for _ in range(len(grouped.y))]
>> py.iplot({
       'data': [Bar(y=grouped.y)],
       'layout': {
           'bargap': 0,
           'xaxis': {
               'ticktext': bins,
               'tickvals': bin_boundaries
           }
       }
   }, validate=False)
```

[image: Grouped and binned bar chart]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I edited the question to be more specific. Is the only way to do what I want above the last method you talk about. Is there no automatic grouping done by the ticks?